# How to display firebase information in my iOS swift listview controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

I am having difficulty getting firebase into my controller. Firebase is working correctly due to me being able to out print to the console. I need to be able to display all data in my app. Please assist!
    //
    //  All.swift
    //  Guaranteed Pricing
    //

[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class All: UINavigationController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var items: [String] = []
var tableView: UITableView!
let cellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView = UITableView(frame:self.view!.frame)
    self.tableView!.delegate = self
    self.tableView!.dataSource = self
    self.tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    self.view?.addSubview(self.tableView)

    let ref = Firebase(url:"https://sizzling-inferno-451.firebaseio.com/services")
    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {

//                let key = child.key //returns -Jikaijsipaij and -kalksdokoas
//                let name = child.value.objectForKey("service_name") as   NSString?
////                
//                self.items.append(key)
        }
        // do some stuff once
        print(snapshot.value)

        // get these values and put them in the cell's text view. key is more important
        print(snapshot.key)



        // add to the array and just this array


        self.tableView!.reloadData()
    })
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Fetch Fruit
    let fruit = items[indexPath.row]

    // Configure Cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = fruit
    return cell
}

// onclick printing
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print(items[indexPath.row])
}
```

}

Comment: Well, for starters you are not populating the items array (which is the tableView data source) with any data. You would want to do that within the ref.observe block. It looks like your code is commented out that you should be using, at least if you just want to display a list of keys. Oh, and your Firebase structure doesn't include any keys called service_name so you should use a key name that exists such as hours or type

Comment: Well the code that I commented out I was trying to model off of a firebase structure. I ended up trying to implement it but instead of service_name I used description. For some reason I keep receiving an error saying "value of optional type 'AnyObject?!' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!'?' or '?' ." Also, do you have any suggestions of how I can populate the array? Or any idea what that errors from? Firebase is working properly and i have the controllers set up correctly...I've been dealing with this error for awhile and Im not sure how to solve it.

Comment: You should probably read up on optionals (the ?) as they are an integral part of Swift - the Apple tutorial on variables and optionals is pretty good. I added an answer which should provide some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet to populate an array within a block, and then once populated reload the tableview to display the data.

```
user_id_0
   name: "Fred"
   friend: "Barney"
```

And the code to read in all of the users, iterate over them and extract each name and add it to an array:

```
    var namesArray: [String] = []

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
               let name = child.value["name"] as! String
               namesArray.append(name)
            }
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
    })
```