# How do I turn a Firebase snapshot into an array of items?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
{ 
    "body": "Hello there",
    "viewers": {
        "1": {
            "user_id": 1
        },
        "2":{
            "user_id": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the snapshot I received from Firebase.

```
        fireRef!.observeEventType(FEventType.Value) { [weak self] (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
            if let stuff = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                print(stuff) //okay, it prints the snapshot correctly
                //Now, I need to access the "viewers" part, but how?
            }
        }
```

How can I loop through each viewer and print the user ID?

Comment: Using numbers as keys in Firebase will lead to a number of issues so you should consider naming your keys with childByAutoId. See the answer to this question [How to display firebase information in my iOS swift listview controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586755/how-to-display-firebase-information-in-my-ios-swift-listview-controller/36607280#36607280). It's a different question but a similar answer.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the tip.  Actually this is just an example. I'm using auto generated IDs in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popped open my last project with Firebase, I was solving this problem as follows:

```
if let viewers = stuff["viewers"] as? [String:[String:Int]] { //Firebase could deliver your numbers as strings, in that case try [String:[String:String]]
                for viewer in viewers {
                    let userID = viewer.1
                    print(userID.values.first)
                }
            }
```

There could be a cleaner way to do it